# Visual Studio Code Java Extension Pack starting template (vscode)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I just changed my editor to vscode and loving it since then.

I am using Java extension pack (specifically project manager I guess), and when I create a new project it generates lib, src/App.java. nothing special.

Is there anyway I can change this default files, folders(package)?
Also, is there anyway I can change this default App.java code?

```java
public class App {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please go through the documentation first.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project)

Answer (score 1):

When you open Command Palette and choose **Java:Create Java Project**, click `No build tools` will generate a template project:

[image]

and this function is provided by extension **Project Manager for Java**:

[image]

To customize templates, find the location of **Project Manager for Java** and change the default ones. On my machine, it's  `C:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-dependency-0.13.0`. There may be many other extensions in your folder **extensions** and you can search it with keyword **java** and its **version number**. For me, the version number is 0.13.0, and you can check it in extension marketplace.

Turn to the directory `C:\Users\...\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-dependency-0.13.0`, open the folder `images` to check if you find the correct one. The `templates` is there and under the directory `templates\invisible-project\src`, you can see `App.java`. Customizing templates like adding and editing files is achievable.

[image]